# Java - If statement if both and each

Tags: java, if-statement

So I have two variables:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 7;
```

Then I have this code:

```
int key = 4; // Can be anything

if (key == x || key == y) {
    if (key == x) {
        // Do something with x
    } else {
        // Do something with y
    }

    // Do something with both x and y
}
```

I get really annoyed to have to write `key == x` 2 times, because in my original code that can be something really long like:

```
key == StaticRandomVeryLongNamedClassName.getARandomNumber()
```

Is there any way to do this without having to write `key == x` two times?

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer but can you assign var `x` like `x = StaticRandomVeryLongNamedClassName.getARandomNumber()`? You could then compare against short `x` instead of this one.

Comment: Yes ok but if I do not want to do that either

Comment: @panther Thanks anyways though

Comment: I know it isn't ideal, but in PHP there is no way (assign to a shorter one variable) how to do that. In Java it will be probably similiar, or the same.

Comment: To avoid stuff like `StaticRandomVeryLongNamedClassName.getARandomNumber()`, you could use a static import: `import static package.Class.staticMethod;` and then just use `staticMethod()` without the class name. But don't use that excessively and try a better structure (with OOP) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign the result of the conditions to local variables...

```
boolean equalsX = key == x;
boolean equalsY = key == y;

if(equalsX || equalsY) {
    if(equalsX) {
    }

    if(equalsY) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With limited details in question, it looks like you don't need nested condition at all and you can do with simple if-elseif:

```
if (key == x) {
    applyX()
    applyCommon()
}
else if (key == y) {
    applyY()
    applyCommon()
}
```

you can do it more in functional style if you are on java8 by composing functions and guarding it by predicate.

```
if (xPredicate.test(key))
    xFunction.apply(key).andThen(commonFunction)
if (yPredicate.test(key))
    yFunction.apply(key).andThen(commonFunction)
```

Comment: I guess the `applyx()` in the `else if` branch was a typo and you meant `applyy()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your original comparison is against something.getARandomNumber, then I suppose the next call gives a different result, so what you are trying to do isn't going to work.

```
Boolean keyX = (key == ...);
Boolean keyY = (key == ...)

if (keyX) { ... } 
if (keyY) { ... }

if (keyX || keyY) { ... }
```